# TextField() Prevent ctrl+a (select all)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

How can I prevent <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>  from functioning with editable TextField()

Comment: Can you add a little more background on what you are trying to accomplish? Maybe TextField isnt the right control for the job?

Comment: well, its perfect ctrl I just want to remove CTRL+A.

Comment: Sound to me like you're trying to do something that you shouldn't do. Could you explain what the reason is that you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous example only works with Flex Text and TextArea objects, this works with all flash.text.* objects.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" creationComplete="init()">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.core.UIComponent;

            private var t:TextField;
            private function init():void
            {
                t = new TextField();
                t.height = 80;
                t.width  = 100;
                t.type   = TextFieldType.INPUT;
                t.multiline = true;
                var c:UIComponent = new UIComponent();
                c.addChild( t );
                foo.addChild( c );
                addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,         edit );
                addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,       edit );
            } 

            private function edit( event:KeyboardEvent ):void
            {
                if( event.type == KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN && event.ctrlKey )
                {
                    t.type = TextFieldType.DYNAMIC; // Dynamic texts cannot be edited.  You might be able to remove this line.
                    t.selectable = false; // If selectable is false, then Ctrl-a won't do anything.
                }
                else
                {
                    t.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
                    t.selectable = true;
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:Canvas id="foo" height="90" width="110" backgroundColor="#FFFFFF" />
</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but perhaps you could catch the [`selectAll` event](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event:selectAll) on the `TextField` and prevent it bubbling up, or clear the selection (not sure when the event is fired).

Comment: its not for FLEX3, its in FLASH PLAYER 10

Comment: Sorry, I assumed from the tag in your question you were using Flex. I have no other ideas that haven't already been suggested. Hope you find an answer.

Comment: I try to be more specific now:  
my question is for FLEX;   but the selectAll event you mentioned is not working with FLEX.  Flex is using flash 9,  but  SelectAll event is available in flash 10 only.

Answer (score 0):

Use the setFocus function paired with a KeyboardEvent listener:

```
<xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- menus/SimpleMenuControl.mxml -->
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" width="800" initialize="init()" >
    <mx:TextInput id="nom"/>
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private function init():void
            {
                addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,     edit );
                addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,   edit );
            } 

            private function edit( event:KeyboardEvent ):void
            {
                if( event.type == KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN && event.ctrlKey ) setFocus();
                else nom.setFocus();
                nom.selectionEndIndex = nom.selectionBeginIndex = nom.text.length;
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

</mx:Application>
```

The setFocus means that the Text object will no longer listen to any keyboard events.

I would not recommend using the enabled property as that will gray-out the textarea.

Comment: setFocus() gives :  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method

Comment: if (evt.ctrlKey) stage.focus = this;   does nothing to ctrl+a

Comment: Sorry.  For some reason, only half of the code appeared above.  I fixed it now.

If you're working in Flex 3, then setFocus() will work on any UIComponent, but there is a modified version below which will work on a normal flash.text.TextField.